# Magento 2 A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website error

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers, customer-address

I'm stuck in a weird problem.

Everytime I try to create an account and add an address to that account programmatically I get an error called

```
A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website
```

This is my code for adding shipping and billing address to customer.

```
$customer->save();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
        //$customerId = $customer->getId();
        //Address info

         $customerAddress = $this->customerFactory->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($customer_email);
         $customerId = $customerAddress->getId();


         $address = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
         $address->setFirstname($parameters["first-name"])
            ->setLastname($parameters["last-name"])
            ->setCountryId("US")
            //->setRegionId("1")
            //->setRegion("")
            ->setCity('n/a')
            ->setPostcode($parameters["zip"])
            ->setCompany('n/a')
            ->setCustomerId($customerId)
            ->setStreet(['n/a'])
            ->setTelephone($parameters["phone"])
            >setIsDefaultBilling(1)
            ->setIsDefaultShipping(1);

        $this->addressRepository->save($address);
```

Of course I'm adding differnt emails everytime I run this controller, but for some reason it keeps telling me that the email is already associated with another customer.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

First you have to check customer in website exist or not ?

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor
    )
    {
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
    }

        public function execute()
        {
            $customerEmail = 'customer email address';
            $websiteId = (int)$this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
            $isEmailNotExists = $this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($customerEmail, $websiteId);
        
            if ($isEmailNotExists == '1') {
                $customerData = ['set your customer Data];
                $request = $this->requestFactory->create();
                $request->setParams($customerData);
                $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $request);
                $password = $this->generatePassword();
                $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->createAccount($customer, $password);
                $this->_customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
            } else {
                $customer = $this->_customer;
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                $customer->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
                $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            }
        }
        
        
        public function generatePassword()
        {
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $randomString = substr(str_shuffle($characters), 0, 10);
            return $randomString;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your forgot this line we got same error.

```
$customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);
```